# What information does the bottom bar in emacs convey?

Tags: emacs, modeline

I've started using emacs recently and am liking it. I've noticed that it always has this bottom area displaying some information about the buffer I have open. A normal appearence might be:

--:--- bufferName All L3 (modebeingviewedin?)------------------------------------

I've noticed the 6 first symbols seem to have something to do with the permissions of the file, and weather or not it has been edited. Other than the buffername I'm not certain how to read any of this bottom line.

What is this thing called? Minibuffer(I thought that was the M-x command prompt)?

What are these sections for/can someone provide a link to more info?

Thanks

Comment: Just hover over different sections in the bar.  Chances are that you'll get all the answers.  Good luck!

Comment: See http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/emacs.html#Mode-Line

Comment: If you find the mode-line difficult to read. You may like smart-mode-line (screenshots at the link). https://github.com/Bruce-Connor/smart-mode-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My question is a duplicate, though I didn't know that at the time of posting.

The area is called the "Mode Line"
The link provided by PP:

http://gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/emacs.html#Mode-Line

provides the current link to a thorough explanation about the the mode. (the duplicate question had an out of date answer, which I noticed PP also commented on)

I found a more concise explanation here, http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ModeLine

Comment: A somewhat more out of the way term is "lighter," which is what emacs calls the abbreviated mode indicators (in parentheses).